# Comparar una variable entre un rango de cifras en PHP

Tags: php

Necesito ayuda para realizar comparaciones entre un rango de numeros entre 0 y 500000

En este caso tenemos la variable salario correspondiente al número de 1000000 que no pertenece al rango declarado, sin embargo, el código me arroja lo contrario.

```html
<?php 
$salario = 1000000;

if($salario >= 0 || $salario <= 500000) {
echo "SI PERTENECE AL RANGO";
} else {
echo "NO PERTENECE AL RANGO"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: De hecho el código si funciona y esta bien, por que si bien no es menor o igual a 500000, si es mayor o igual a 0; es decir como estás usando el operador OR este devolverá true cuando al menos 1 de las condiciones sea cierta, es decir la condición de la izquierda si es cierta y la derecha no, por eso te indica que si pertenece al rango

Comment: Si necesitas que ambas condiciones sean ciertas para validar que el número realmente pertenece a un rango dado, entonces lo que debes hacer es cambiar ese operador por el operador `AND` para indicar que solo será true cuando ambas condiciones sean ciertas

Comment: Te recomiendo [leas a detalle la doc. oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php) ya que esto es mas un problema de comprensión

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es elemental. El operador OR `||` es verdadero cuando al menos uno de los dos valores comparados es verdadero. Para lo que deseas hacer necesitas que se cumplan las dos condiciones y sea falso cuando una de ellas sea falsa. Para ello existe el operador AND `&&`

Tu código se corrige escribiendo:

```
<?php
$salario = 1000000;
// Observa los signos de agrupación. Son muy importantes para fijar las condiciones
if( ($salario >= 0) && ($salario <= 500000) ) {
    echo "SI PERTENECE AL RANGO";
} else {
    echo "NO PERTENECE AL RANGO"; 
}
```

Por favor lee la documentación oficial: [Operadores de comparación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php) está disponible en español

Comment: Considera agregarle un enlace a la doc. para que se familiarice con este tema: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Inmediatamente lo hago

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora sí funciona en base a lo que necesito